# Can this Cartesian product of dictionary entries be done using recursion?

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary, recursion

I am working on a simple way to define in a compact way different classification experiments to be instantiated and evaluated automatically, to obtain the best possible algorithm and parameter combination for a particular problem.

Here is the particular part of the code that makes the Cartesian product that produces all the possible combinations of parameter values:

```
def unpack_parameters(parameters_list):
    parameters = []
    for parameter_name, parameter_values in parameters_list.items():
        if len(parameters) == 0:
            parameters = [{parameter_name: parameter_value} for parameter_value in parameter_values]
        else:
            parameters = [dict(parameter.items() + {parameter_name: parameter_value}.items())
                          for parameter_value in parameter_values for parameter in parameters]

    return parameters
```

**¿Can I get to the same result by using recursion?**

The code above works and produces the desired results. I'm also aware that I could use itertools.product to get the same results. But this is a question for learning if recursion could be used here, more than if it is the right tool for solving the specific problem (although I wouldn't mind comments on this).

In case anyone is interested, here is how this code is used:

```
experiment_definitions = {
    'sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier':
        {'criterion': ['entropy', 'gini'],
         'min_samples_split': [2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64]}
}
classifiers = {}
for classifier_class, parameters_list in experiment_definitions.items():
    classifiers[classifier_class] = unpack_parameters(parameters_list)
```

To produce this:

```
{'sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier': 
[{'min_samples_split': 2, 'criterion': 'entropy'}, {'min_samples_split': 4, 'criterion': 'entropy'}, {'min_samples_split': 8, 'criterion': 'entropy'}, {'min_samples_split': 16, 'criterion': 'entropy'}, {'min_samples_split': 32, 'criterion': 'entropy'}, {'min_samples_split': 64, 'criterion': 'entropy'}, {'min_samples_split': 2, 'criterion': 'gini'}, {'min_samples_split': 4, 'criterion': 'gini'}, {'min_samples_split': 8, 'criterion': 'gini'}, {'min_samples_split': 16, 'criterion': 'gini'}, {'min_samples_split': 32, 'criterion': 'gini'}, {'min_samples_split': 64, 'criterion': 'gini'}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the trick is to be able to write a function `cartesian_product()` which takes as input a list of numbers and returns a cartesian product of the indices considering that the numbers could be the size of a list.

For example, if we have 2 lists of sizes 2 and 6 (as per your example), then `cartesian_product([2, 6])` should generate the output:

`[[0, 0], [1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1], [0, 2], [1, 2], [0, 3], [1, 3], [0, 4], [1, 4], [0, 5], [1, 5]]`

```py
def cartesian_product(sizes, start=0):
    if not sizes:
        return []
    if start == len(sizes) - 1:
        return [[i] for i in range(sizes[-1])]
    sub_answer_lists = cartesian_product(sizes, start+1)
    ans = []
    for sub_ans_list in sub_answer_lists:
        for j in range(sizes[start]):
            list_copy = [j]
            list_copy.extend(sub_ans_list)
            ans.append(list_copy)
    return ans


def unpack_parameters(params_dict):
    param_keys = []
    param_lists = []
    for key, lst in params_dict.items():
        param_keys.append(key)
        param_lists.append(lst)
    param_lists_sizes = [len(lst) for lst in param_lists]
    cartesian_product_indices = cartesian_product(param_lists_sizes)
    param_map_list = []
    for indices in cartesian_product_indices:
        param_map = {}
        for i, index in enumerate(indices):
            param_key = param_keys[i]
            param_map[param_key] = param_lists[i][index]
        param_map_list.append(param_map)
    return param_map_list


experiment_definitions = {
    'sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier':
        {'criterion': ['entropy', 'gini'],
         'min_samples_split': [2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64]}
}
classifiers = {}
for classifier_class, params_dict in experiment_definitions.items():
    classifiers[classifier_class] = unpack_parameters(params_dict)

print(classifiers)
```

Output:

```
{'sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier': [{'criterion': 'entropy', 'min_samples_split': 2}, {'criterion': 'gini', 'min_samples_split': 2}, {'criterion': 'entropy', 'min_samples_split': 4}, {'criterion': 'gini', 'min_samples_split': 4}, {'criterion': 'entropy', 'min_samples_split': 8}, {'criterion': 'gini', 'min_samples_split': 8}, {'criterion': 'entropy', 'min_samples_split': 16}, {'criterion': 'gini', 'min_samples_split': 16}, {'criterion': 'entropy', 'min_samples_split': 32}, {'criterion': 'gini', 'min_samples_split': 32}, {'criterion': 'entropy', 'min_samples_split': 64}, {'criterion': 'gini', 'min_samples_split': 64}]}
```

**EDIT**:

A generator version using far less memory:

```py
def cartesian_product(sizes, start=0):
    if not sizes:
        yield []
        return
    if start == len(sizes) - 1:
        for i in range(sizes[-1]):
            yield [i]
        return
    for sub_ans_list in cartesian_product(sizes, start+1):
        for j in range(sizes[start]):
            list_copy = [j]
            list_copy.extend(sub_ans_list)
            yield list_copy
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, something like this:

```
def product(names, values, current=[])
  pos = len(current)
  if pos >= len(names):
     # a solution
     solutions.append(current.copy())
     return
  for v in values[pos]:
    current.append((names[pos], v)
    product(names, values, current)
    current.pop()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @sorin, but I don't see how to apply this to the problem above. What would you pass as names and what as values?